# $μ$-law: What operation is being performed in the $μ|x|$ portion of the algorithm?

Tags: signal-processing

According to [wikipedia $\mu$-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) is:
$$F(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x)\frac{\ln(1+\mu|x|)}{\ln(1+\mu)} \qquad -1\le x \le 1$$

where $μ = 255$ ($8$ bits) in the North American and Japanese standards (This is a signal processing algorithm).

What operation is being performed in the $\mu|x|$ portion of the above algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean, what does $|x|$ represent? It's the absolute value of $x$ e.g. $|-1/2|=|1/2|=1/2$.

Comment: suppose $x =\frac{127}{256} \approx 0.5$, $F(x)= \frac{log(128)}{log(256)}=0.875$. Now, if you consider that in this context 0.875 is better than 0.5 ...

Comment: I do understand $|x|$ is the abs(x). What I don't get is that $\mu$. Is this simply equal to 255 * abs(x)?